# How to make a bot send a message to a specific channel after receiving a reaction from a certain message

Tags: async-await, discord.js, message

So I'm trying to develop a bot for a very small project (I'm not a programmer or anything, just need to do this one thing). All I need it to do is to collect reactions from a specific message I sent and send another message to a channel as soon as it detects a reaction. The message would contain the reactor's tag and some text. I would need it to be activelly collecting reactions all the time, without any limit. I tried looking through the documentation but I don't really know how to implement the .awaitmessageReactions or whatever it's called. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use method [`createReactionCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector) for this. But when bot go down, this collector will stop.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
let targetChannelId = '1232132132131231';
bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`${bot.user.tag} is ready on ${bot.guilds.cache.size} servers!`);
});

bot.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.content === 'test') {
        message.channel.send(`i\`m await of reactions on this message`).then((msg) => {
            const filter = (reaction, user) => !user.bot;
            const collector = msg.createReactionCollector(filter);
            collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
                let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(targetChannelId);
                if (channel) {
                    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
                    embed.setAuthor(
                        user.tag,
                        user.displayAvatarURL({
                            dynamic: true,
                            format: 'png',
                        }),
                    );
                }
                embed.setDescription(`${user} (${user.tag}) has react a: ${reaction.emoji}`);
                channel.send(embed);
            });
            collector.on('end', (reaction, reactionCollector) => {
                msg.reactions.removeAll();
            });
        });
    }
});

bot.login('token');
```

Or you can use emitter [`messageReactionAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) and handle reaction on specific message.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const token = require('./token.json').token
const bot = new Discord.Client({ partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'] });

bot.once('ready', () => {
    console.log(`${bot.user.tag} is ready on ${bot.guilds.cache.size} guilds`)
})

let targetChannelId = '668497133011337224'

bot.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.partial) {
        // If the message this reaction belongs to was removed the fetching might result in an API error, which we need to handle
        try {
            await reaction.fetch();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Something went wrong when fetching the message: ', error);
            // Return as `reaction.message.author` may be undefined/null
            return;
        }
    }

    if (reaction.message.id === '730000158745559122') {
        let channel = reaction.message.guild.channels.cache.get(targetChannelId);
        console.log(reaction.emoji)
        if (channel) {
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
            embed.setAuthor(
                user.tag,
                user.displayAvatarURL({
                    dynamic: true,
                    format: 'png',
                }),
            );
            embed.setDescription(`${user} has react a: ${reaction.emoji}`);
            channel.send(embed);
        }
    }
});

bot.login(token)
```

Comment: I tried it out. The first one did reply once I sent a message, but didn't seem to collect any reactions I added. The second one (which is pretty much what I need) didn't really do anything, even when I asked someone else to add a reaction.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did. I placed the channel ID on "targetChannelId", the message ID on "SOME ID" and my token in the token bracket. Is there something else I need to fill in?

Comment: i'm sorry, forgot about partials, thats need no handle reaction on non cached messages. I'm edit my solution, now its work correctly

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly now.
I hope I'm not taking too much of your time, but is it possible to send an embed (much like that one) to a specific channel, instead of replying on the same one?

Comment: Sure, just get an another channel with let anotherChannel = reaction.message.guild.channels.cache.get('ID HERE'); anotherChannel.send(embed)